# Get camera zoomlevel from googlemaps in Kotlin

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I want to get the camerazoomlevel in googlemaps, so that I can resize my markers depending on the zoomlevel. I know that I can set the zoomlevel as in 
`mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Berlin, zoomLevel))` but is there any way to get a feedback from googlemaps or make googlemaps change the iconsize automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it,
you can just do: `mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener { println("zoomed") }`
this opens automatically when you zoomed

Answer (score 0):

```
val center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LatLng(latitude, longitude))
val zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13)

mMap.moveCamera(center)
mMap.animateCamera(zoom)
```

Comment: Please describe what your code does and how it answers the question.